# XAMPP redirect not working

Tags: php, xampp

I recently installed xampp but the redirects to index.php are not working

can you please help me?
I want to do this:
redirect this

localhost/myweb/
to this
localhost/myweb/index.php
thanks

Comment: In project folder if you add any index.php then automatically call that index.php file no need to any redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

localhost/myweb/ IS localhost/myweb/index.php

By going to "/myweb/" you are basically going to "/myweb/index.php".

Comment: thought so, but localhost/myweb/  is showing me an error that page was not found

Comment: Try rebooting it? Maybe that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just go type in the url localhost following with the web name